# Why do I get 'Invalid syntax' for this function call?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the program -

```
def sum3or5muls(lim):
    mulsum = 0
    for i in range(1, lim+1):
        if i%3==0 or i%5==0 and not(i%3==0 and i%5==0):
            print i, mulsum
            mulsum += i
        return mulsum

print sum3or5muls(1000)
```

I keep getting 'Invalid syntax' under the t in the print call on the last line. I've tried various remedies but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Edit: It may be because chrome python is prompt only so I didn't leave edit mode... Yep, that was it - would normally supply a text file not do everything at the prompt. If anyone would like to fix this for this version of python feel free. Two other things: there should be parenthesis around the first two conditions in the 'if' clause and return has to move back.

Comment: are you sure this is Python2?

Comment: How do you run your script? `python …` or `./myscript.py` with a shebang?

Comment: I ran your code as it came and got `0`. Not intended I would assume, but no errors..

Comment: Using python2 style print statements in python3 gives the syntax error as the end of the first thing to print (would be the s of sum3or5muls) not the t.

Comment: @Thecheater887 Probably due to the bad indentation of the return. OP should remove one indentation level on this line.

Comment: To get the actual version of python do `import sys` and `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: If `sys.version` fails, try to only print by issuing `print "Hello, world!"` and nothing else (if that throws `SyntaxError` we know that the implementation ought to be kind of python3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut and pasting that code into my editor sees it working perfectly under Python 2 (Python 3 would have complained about the first `print` rather than the last one).

It prints zero but that's due to your `return` statement is *inside* the loop rather than after it (so it only does the one iteration).

My only suggestion is to look at the file in more detail to make sure you haven't mixed tabs and spaces, that there's no spaces on the second-to-last line and that there aren't any funny invisible characters in there.

For example, you could do this under Linux with:

```
od -xcb myprog.py
```

Comment: I didn't even get round to testing the logic. The fact that apart from that it works means there's something wrong with the version.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using Python 3 (you can confirm that using `python --version`).

You can either fix your code to work on Python 3 by adding parentheses around your `print` calls:

```
print(i, mulsum)
...
print(sum3or5muls(1000))
```

Or, install Python 2 and actually run that (it might already be installed under the name `python2`).

Comment: It's Python 2.7.7 on Chrome. It says so.

Comment: @mistermarko Python doesn't run natively in Chrome. Are you using an extension?

Comment: There is a version that does but it's prompt only, no files.

Comment: He should not run `python --version` but rather _his-current-python_ `--version`

Comment: @mistermarko If you don't tell us what version that is, we can't help you. Where did you find that version of Python?

Comment: If it was py3, it would have complained about the *first* `print`, not the last.

Comment: @paxdiablo Good point. Looks like it's not clear what Python this is.

Comment: You can just download apps for chrome from google. Someone wrote a linux interpreter and this is it but there's not much info on the project, and it doesn't seem to work anyway because other people didn't get that error.

Comment: @paxdiablo no, because the interpreter would look into the function only when it is called, and it is called on `print sum3or5muls(1000)` thus the error on this line.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Try it.  SyntaxError is thrown when the function is defined not when it's called.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger `SyntaxError` is thrown when the source is compiled, you even get the error **before** the function is even defined, or any of the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, many things can cause the error you're getting:

- You're using Python version < 3
- Mixing tabs and spaces

Try to run the code in your machine, just open a file, copy the code into it and run it.

After you probably know why your code doesn't run, it's time to fix the code itself so it gives good results. Note the following:

- You're returning the result after only one iteration, you should move the `return` to outside the loop
- Your condition can be simplified and reduced

Answer (score 0):

Calling your function by using "print()" command this is work by entering your calling between parentheses for the command.

From your example:

```
...
print (sum3or5muls(1000))
```

**NOTE:**

Your post since 2015. So, it is, perhaps, the new version of Python *(Which is at this moment is v3.7.0)* has been solved the issue. Anyway, I am using the Python v3.6.1 operated by "Repl.it".

Kind Regards,

Ali.Works